# Enable Zend Multibyte Support in PHP

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework, yum

I have installed PHP (5.3.23) using yum on Amazon Linux server. I have also installed mbstring using:

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

But the Zend Multibyte Support is showing as disabled. How can I enable it? I don't want to install PHP from source.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.multibyte - in short, it's a php.ini directive, just turn it on, but it won't have any effect because it only applies to PHP>=5.4.0+

Comment: Thanks for sharing that Dave, I have seen that. That would have been an easier fix! So it won't possible to get that done in any way for 5.3.23 php version?

Comment: Tried zend.multibyte=On - not working, still it is showing disabled.

Comment: @Jeyasithar, That's only for 5.4+

Answer (score 2):

You need to build PHP with the `--enable-zend-multibyte` option.

Comment: Just as a side-note, this option has been removed in PHP 5.4 and above.